# Python erratic behaviour: /usr/bin/python: No module named hotspotd.hotspotd

Tags: python, linux

I'm quite new to python and just created my first opensource python project - a [daemon](https://github.com/prahladyeri/hotspotd) to create wifi hotspots on linux.

I've used distutils to build the package. To start the daemon once installation is done, I've registered the below script that simply starts the daemon by calling the corresponding python module:

```
#!/bin/bash
python -m hotspotd $*
```

And this is the setup.py that registers it:

```
#INSTALL IT
from distutils.core import setup
s = setup(name='hotspotd',
    version='0.1',
    description='Small daemon to create a wifi hotspot on linux',
    license='MIT',
    author='Prahlad Yeri',
    author_email='prahladyeri@yahoo.com',
    url='https://github.com/prahladyeri/hotspotd',
    #py_modules=['hotspotd','cli'],
    packages=['hotspotd'],
    package_dir={'hotspotd': ''},
    package_data={'hotspotd': ['run.dat']},
    scripts=['hotspotd']
    #data_files=[('config',['run.dat'])],
    )
```

Now, this works fine on my machine and some other machines I've tested. However, as indicated by the open issue on the github, some users are unable to run that script. It gives the error:

```
No module named hotspotd.main; 'hotspotd' is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

Apparently it expects the entire *package.module* syntax which is `hotspotd.hotspotd` on their setups. However, on my machine the full syntax doesn't work, and only `hotspotd` works. Whats going on here?

Comment: Out of context, you should use "$@" instead of $*, more safe. From man bash: "When the expansion occurs within double quotes, each
 parameter  expands  to  a  separate  word.  That is, "$@" is equivalent to "$1" "$2" ..."

Comment: @JulienPalard - Thanks for letting me know that. However, I'm awaiting the solution to the issue in question.

Comment: I can understand that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change my script, so that instead of directly passing the module as argument, I import this module in the script itself and call the `hotspotd.main` function from there:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#@author: Prahlad Yeri
#@description: Small daemon to create a wifi hotspot on linux
#@license: MIT
#python -m hotspotd $*
import hotspotd.main
import sys
import os
import argparse


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #check root or not
    if os.getenv('USER') != 'root':
        print "You need root permissions to do this, sloth!"
        sys.exit(1)

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='A small daemon to create a wifi hotspot on linux')
    parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', required=False, action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('command', choices=['start', 'stop', 'configure'])
    args = parser.parse_args()
    hotspotd.main.main(args)
```